# Why is makefile shell result different than doing same in shell?

Tags: shell, makefile, gnu-make

With a GNU makefile content of:

```
SVNVERSION_NUMBER := $(shell svnversion --version | perl -lne 'print $1 if /version (\d+.\d+.\d+)/')

$(error $(SVNVERSION_NUMBER))
```

I get a result of:

```
Makefile:3: *** svnversion, version 1.6.2 (r37639).  Stop.
```

However, at the shell if I type:

```
svnversion --version | perl -lne 'print $1 if /version (\d+.\d+.\d+)/'
```

I get the result:

```
1.6.2
```

Clearly, my shell syntax is not doing what I think it is, but I'm not clear on why.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$ is special in make strings.  $$ for a literal dollar sign in the perl command.